# Shared object "libarchive.so.5" not found, required by "pkg"

Tags: freebsd

I just updated my FreeBSD from 9.x to 10.0 (using `freebsd-update`) and now my `pkg` isn't working.

```
# pkg
Shared object "libarchive.so.5" not found, required by "pkg"
#
```

I know I can use `pkg-static` meanwhile, but how do I fix my `pkg` now?

*** UPDATE ***:

```
# pkg-static  info pkg
pkg-static: No package(s) matching pkg
# pkg-static install pkg
Updating repository catalogue
pkg-static: http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/latest/repo.txz: Not Found
#
```

Comment: Did you [rebuild all your ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html#freebsdupdate-upgrade), e.g. `portmaster -af`?

Comment: when I try doing that, I get : `/usr/local/sbin/portmaster: pkg_version: not found`

Comment: Well now I have to wonder if you ever properly converted to pkgng?

Comment: I just used `freebsd-update` fetch & install && reboot

Comment: (upstream portmaster maintainer here) Sounds like a portmaster bug there. It runs 'pkg info pkg' to see if pkg is installed, and since it is erroring due to the shared lib then it thinks pkg is not installed and uses the old pkg_*. I will try to address that.

Comment: @BryanDrewery I just updated my question.

Comment: Rebuild `pkg` from ports: `cd /usr/ports/port-mgmt/pkg && make deinstall reinstall clean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what fixed my FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE -> 10.0-RELEASE update which had the identical issue `Shared object "libarchive.so.5" not found required by "pkg"`, though my `pkg-static pkg` showed `1.2.6` was installed.

```
# pkg-static bootstrap -f
```

Which listed instructions for boot strapping pkg

```
# pkg-static delete -f pkg
# /usr/sbin/pkg -v
```

Afterwards pkg seems to behave correctly.

Comment: `pkg-static: 'bootstrap' is not a valid command.`

Comment: I still get: `pkg-static boostrap` `pkg(8) already installed, use -f to force.`

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Rebuild `pkg` from ports:

   ```
   cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg && make deinstall reinstall clean
   ```
2. Fix the library link via `libmap.conf`:

   ```
   echo "libarchive.so.5 `ls /usr/lib/libarchive.so.*`" >> /etc/libmap.conf
   ```

   There might be other apps that this fixes the same issue. `pkg` also relies on 8 other shared libraries. I'm not sure which changed between 9.x and 10.x, but I'd bet there will be others.